# How to encrypt array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encryption

So I see `digest(data text, type text) returns bytea` but is there any way to apply this to an array type (`bytea[]`) on insert?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table(my_val) VALUES(digest($1, 'type'));
```

is how you'd use it for a non-array value, but how would I apply this to an array?

Comment: digest does not encrypt, is hashes.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast anything to text....

so cast the array to text and then hash that.

```
INSERT INTO table(my_val) VALUES(digest(cast(data as text), type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the array to text and encrypt using `crypt()` function, because digest does not encrypt.

```
INSERT INTO table(my_val) VALUES(crypt(cast(data as text), type), gen_salt('md5'));
```

You can also use the `hmac()` function,
This is similar to `digest()` but the hash can only be recalculated knowing the key.
This prevents the scenario of someone altering data and also changing the hash to match.

This [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgcrypto.html) explains well.